# Setting visibility of stacked item on a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, visibility

I'm attempting to show either a textbox or a button in a stack panel on a datagrid, based on a drop down in a different column in a WPF datagrid. Below is the basic code. The actual implementation would have binding values to a data source for each field.  Looking for a simple elegant way to set visibility of the textbox and button based on selected value from dropdown.  Any help is appreciated:

```
<Grid Name="dg1">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" Name="dataGrid1" Width="500" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel  Height="30">
                            <TextBox   Name="tbName"  Width="100" />
                            <Button Name="btn1" Content="ADD ME" Width="100" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Choice" Width="150" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox  Name="combo1" >
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="ShowButton" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="ShowText" />
                        </ComboBox>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I have an ANSWER...
After analyzing the first reply was able to piece together the following solution

XAML

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:ChoiceToVisibilityConverter x:Key="choice2visibilityConverter" />
    <local:ChoiceList x:Key="ChoiceList" />
</Window.Resources>
 <Grid Name="dg1">
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" Name="dataGrid1" Width="500" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel  Height="30">
                        <TextBox   Name="tbName"  Width="100" Visibility="{Binding Choice, Converter={StaticResource choice2visibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=TextBox} />
                        <Button Name="btn1" Content="ADD ME" Width="100" Visibility="{Binding Choice, Converter={StaticResource choice2visibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=TextBox} />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Choice" Width="150" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox  Name="combo1"  
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding Choice, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                  ItemsSource="{StaticResource ChoiceList }"
                                   >

                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C# Code:

```
 public  class ChoiceToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString().CompareTo("ShowText") == 0)
            return Visibility.Visible ;
        return Visibility.Hidden ;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class ChoiceList : List<string>
{
    public ChoiceList()
    {

        this.Add("ShowText");
        this.Add("ShowButton");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your DataGrid is binded to a Collection of your model class that contains information about a single row.

you can simply add a property `SelectedRow` and bind it with the DataGrid  `SelectedItem` property. in your column data template, use value converters and binding to show/hide whatever you want accordingly.

something like that:

```
<Window.Resources>
            <local:ChoiceToVisibilityConverter x:Key="choice2visibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

 <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel  Height="30">
                        <TextBox   Name="tbName"  Width="100"  Visibility="{Binding SelectedRow.Choice, Converter={StaticResource choice2visibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=fromTextBox}"/>
                        <Button Name="btn1" Content="ADD ME" Width="100"  Visibility="{Binding SelectedRow.Choice, Converter={StaticResource choice2visibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=fromButton}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Choice" Width="150" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox  Name="combo1"  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedRow.Choice}" SelectedValuePath="Content" >
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="ShowButton" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="ShowText" />
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

so here you can choose the visibilty to return in the ValueConverter based on the Selected choise and on the converter parameter.

Comment: The answer you gave provided enough direction to find the correct solution..  see below...

Comment: That's a much complete and better solution :)